# Fliping just one direction

Tags: flutter, flip, card

In flutter there is a pack for flipping card, But when tap its first view - turns into second view.  Same as, its turn into second to first view.
But I want to turn into first to second only. Not again reversible.How can I make it, pls.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also configure the card to only flip when desired by using a GlobalKey to toggle the cards:

GlobalKey<FlipCardState> cardKey = GlobalKey<FlipCardState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FlipCard(
    key: cardKey,
    flipOnTouch: false,
    front: Container(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => cardKey.currentState.toggleCard(),
        child: Text('Toggle'),
      ),
    ),
    back: Container(
      child: Text('Back'),
    ),
  );
}
```

You can do some logic to togglecard once and then the change the onPressed to an empty function